# Palindrome from a file in python

Tags: python, loops, file

I wanted to check if a word is a palindrome in *dane.txt* and create zadanie.txt with these palindromes, but code don't save anything in file *zadanie.txt*.

```py
with open('dane.txt', 'r') as reader:
    with open('zadanie.txt', 'w') as writer:
        for line in reader:
            if line == line[::-1]:
                writer.write(line)
```

Comment: You are missing extra indentation at line 2 and onwards.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue most probably derives from the fact that a line is ending in newline characters, try to strip the line and check for palindromes that way, e.g.:

```py
with open("dane.txt", "r") as reader:
    with open("zadanie.txt", "w") as writer:
        for line in reader:
            stripped_line = line.strip()
            if stripped_line == stripped_line[::-1]:
                writer.write(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

If that doesn't work, you could always just split it into 2 loops?

```
out = []
with open('dane.txt', 'r') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        if line == line[::-1]:
            out.append(line)
with open('zadanie.txt', 'w') as writer:
    for line in out:
        writer.write(line)
```

This is assuming your search for palindrome is working, that would be the first check!

Comment: Actually it will fail, since the line is ending in a newline character, which makes it asymmetric even if the text is a palindrome.